# Classifying Differential Equations with an exponent in the dependent variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why is the following equation not linear ?
$$ y\frac{dy}{dx}  + (\sin x)y^3 = e^x + 1 $$

when this one is linear:
$$(\sin x)\frac{dy}{dx}+(\cos x)y = x^2$$

They both appear to be written in what I think is the general form:

$$a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_0(x)y=b(x) $$

Why does the exponent for $y^3$ make the first one non-linear?

Comment: Your general form does not have the cubed $y$, and does not have $y$ be a linear factor of $a_{1}(x)$, and this makes all the difference.

Comment: Because $y^3$ isn't a linear function in $y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equation is linear if and only if: (1) the sum of two solutions to the homogeneous version, i.e.,
$$
y {dy \over dx} + \sin(x) y^3 = 0, \quad \mbox{(homogeneous version)}
$$
is also a solution, and
(2) if a scalar multiple of a solution is also a solution.

Well, let $y_1, y_2$ be two solutions of the (homogeneous version).  Is their sum a solution?  No:
$$
(y_1 + y_2) {d (y_1 + y_2) \over dx} + \sin(x) (y_1 + y_2)^3 \neq
\left[y_1 {dy_1 \over dx} + \sin(x) y_1^3\right] + \left[y_2 {dy_2 \over x} + \sin(x) y_2^3\right],
$$
because the cross terms that are present on the left-hand side are absent on the right-hand side.  Similarly, if $y$ were a solution, one can find a scalar such that $cy$ would not be a solution.

However, your second ODE is of the general form you wrote, so is linear.